# Getting original tweet-id and user-id from retweet-id

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Twitter4j to access the streaming API. I am using `follow`, to get a stream related to a set of users. 
My problem basically boils down to this: Given a **retweet** (I have the retweet-id and the user-id of the retweet) in the stream, how can I find:

1. the userID of the original tweet
2. the tweetID of the original tweet

I don't suppose the API exposes this, does it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the userID and the tweetID of the original tweet you need to do inside onStatus:

```
@Override
public void onStatus(Status status) {
 if(status.isretweet()){
  Status originalTweet = status.getRetweetedStatus();
  long originaltweetid = originalTweet.getId();
  long originaluserid = originalTweet.getUser().getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up. What if the said retweet was a in fact a retweet of a retweet? `status.getRetweetedStatus()` returns the original tweet that was first tweeted right? I want to get the tweet in between. Is this possible?

Comment: status.getRetweetedStatus() returns the original first tweet, and you can't get the tweet in between, sorry. If A rt B and B rt C, and you capture A you'll get the status from C